# Why there is a while loop in Backbone's set method?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model-view-controller

[Github source code](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L339-L405)

Below is the snippet of Backbone's set method:

```
set: function(key, val, options) {
  var attr, attrs, unset, changes, silent, changing, prev, current;

  ...

  options || (options = {});

  ...

  // Trigger all relevant attribute changes.
  if (!silent) {
    if (changes.length) this._pending = options;
    for (var i = 0, length = changes.length; i < length; i++) {
      this.trigger('change:' + changes[i], this, current[changes[i]], options);
    }
  }

  // You might be wondering why there's a `while` loop here. Changes can
  // be recursively nested within `"change"` events.
  if (changing) return this;
  if (!silent) {
    while (this._pending) {
      options = this._pending;
      this._pending = false;
      this.trigger('change', this, options);
    }
  }
  this._pending = false;
  this._changing = false;
  return this;
}
```

Although the comment did mention the `while` loop I'm wondering about, I fail to see how this while loop work since the local variable `changing` will always be `true` in one round of `set`.

Could anyone explain to me why there is a while and when will it take effect?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Interesting question. Don't know the answer, I'd have to test things out to know. But notice that if `changing` is true, then it exits before the while loop. If you look back a bit earlier, changing will always be false on the first change event. Now if the change event in the while loop triggers another change event then those subsequent changes exit before while loop. Not sure why though. Haha.

Comment: What happens if a listener to `'change'` events calls `set`?

Comment: @muistooshort is that what your think the comment `Changes can
  // be recursively nested within `"change"` events` means? That someone is calling set on a `change` event?

Comment: @Seebiscuit: That's my guess but I'm not sure. As to why it is a `while` instead of `if`, I have no idea.

Comment: @muistooshort my question exactly!

Answer (score 1):

As the comment says, "Changes can be recursively nested within `"change"` events."

It's not uncomment to update or re-set certain properties on your model when a `"change"` event is fired aka making another call to `set`. The `_pending` property is just there to make sure that all properties that are updated on a `"change"` even are in fact changed.

Looks like they used to check if there's additional changes, and if there are backbone used to fire [just 1 change event](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/commit/9c55b4b3498329eb413bafc737fc1a711fafda98#diff-0d56d0d310de7ff18b3cef9c2f8f75dcL341). The problem with this is that if there is a listener to the change event that updates *multiple* properties, not all `set` functions will be called. See [this unit test](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/commit/9c55b4b3498329eb413bafc737fc1a711fafda98#diff-76a1f59f51f8e8a628d3aed19353ace0R753) for a concrete example. So the `while` loop takes care of the edge case of 1 listener calling `set` multiple times, not multiple listeners, each calling `set` once. Like this one in the test linked above:

```
model.on('change:a', function() {
  model.set({b: true});
  model.set({b: true});
});
```

If you're confused about why they change `this._pending` to options, check out [this issue](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/issues/2846) & [the associated pull request](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/commit/47331efca8bde95086a6362c9982683084f74095)

Comment: thank you for your kind answer, however, I changed the `while` in Backbone's set method to `if`, it still produces the same result.

Comment: You're right, it wouldn't matter because each new call to set will change again, only if it's not currently pending. An if will perform the same check.

Comment: so there is no extra meaning for using `while` here instead of `if`?